# Checking if a Date is Valid in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date, if-statement, switch-statement

So as to not mislead anyone, this is a HW problem that I am attempting to complete and need a little help with. The problem itself is pretty self-explanatory. I have to write a function where I input a string 'Month Day, Year' and have it tell me whether or not it's valid (true or false statements). I have it working for almost everything, except now it doesn't seem to recognize my constraints for possible days.

```
function[valid] = isValidDate(str)
[date, year] = strtok(str, ','); %Should give me the date and year
[~, year2] = strtok(year, ' ');
[month, day] = strtok(date, ' '); %Should give me month and the day
day = round(day);
if length(date) < 6
valid = false;
elseif month(1) == upper(month(1))
    valid = true;
elseif length(date) >= 12
    valid = false;
   end
if year2 >= 0
    valid = true;
else
    valid = false;
end
leapyear = mod(year, 400) == 0 | (mod(year, 4) == 0 ~= mod(year, 100) == 0);

switch month
   case {'September','April','June','November'}

 day <= 30;
    valid = true;
    case {'February'}
        if leapyear
            day <= 29;
            valid = true;
        else
            day <= 28;
            valid = true;
        end
    case {'January', 'March', 'May', 'July', 'August', 'October', 'December'} 
        days <= 31;
        valid = true;
otherwise
    valid = false;

end
end
```

So basically

```
valid4 = isValidDate('December 29.9, -1005.7')
valid = false
```

Note: There will be no suffix after the day. My only issue now is that my function doesn't realize my constraints on days. it likes to think 'February 30, 2014' is possible

Comment: What the date's string format?

Comment: "Month, Day Year' so 'January 29, 2012'

Comment: Could you elaborate on `"no suffix after the day"`? Any example that could explain what you meant there?

Comment: It's not January 29th, it's just January 29

Comment: So if I input - `"isValidDate('December 2th, 1934')"` or `"isValidDate('December 2st, 1934')"`, it must output false? That could really complicate things inside the code.

Comment: Or would you like to neglect those suffixes altogether?

Comment: There won't be any of the 'th' or 'st' put in, so we can ignore that. Basically what I was trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
function[valid] = isValidDate(str)

[date1, year1] = strtok(str, ','); %Should give me the date and year
[month1, day1] = strtok(date1, ' '); %Should give me month and the day

%// 1. Take care of bad month strings
all_months = {'January', 'February','March', 'April', 'May','June',...
    'July', 'August', 'September','October','November' 'December'} ;
if ~ismember(cellstr(month1),all_months)
    valid = false;
    return;
end

%// 2. Take care of negative or fraction days
day1 = day1(isstrprop(day1,'digit')); %// Take care of suffixes after day string
num_day = str2double(day1);
if round(num_day)~=num_day || num_day<1
    valid = false;
    return;
end

%// 3. Take care of fraction or negative years
num_year = str2double(strtok(year1,','));
if round(num_year)~=num_year || num_year<0
    valid = false;
    return;
end

lpyr =mod(num_year, 400) == 0 | (mod(num_year, 4) == 0 ~= mod(num_year, 100) == 0);

switch month1
    case {'September','April','June','November'}
        if num_day > 30
            valid = false;
            return;
        end
    case {'February'}
        if (lpyr && num_day > 29) | (~lpyr && num_day > 28)
            valid = false;
            return;
        end
    case {'January', 'March', 'May', 'July', 'August', 'October', 'December'}
        if num_day > 31;
            valid = false;
            return;
        end
end
valid = true; %// We made it through!

return;
```

---

If you would prefer a compact code -

```
function valid = isValidDate(str)

[date1, year1] = strtok(str, ','); %Should give me the date and year
[month1, day1] = strtok(date1, ' '); %Should give me month and the day

%// 1. Take care of bad month strings
all_months = {'January', 'February','March', 'April', 'May','June',...
    'July', 'August', 'September','October','November' 'December'} ;
valid_month = ismember(cellstr(month1),all_months);

%// 2. Take care of negative or fraction days
day1 = day1(isstrprop(day1,'digit')); %// Take care of suffixes after day string
num_day = str2double(day1);
valid_day = round(num_day)==num_day && num_day>=1;

%// 3. Take care of fraction or negative years
num_year = str2double(strtok(year1,','));
valid_year = round(num_year)==num_year && num_year>=0;

%// 4. Take care of valid days based on leap year and days in a month limits
lpyr = mod(num_year, 400) == 0 | (mod(num_year, 4) == 0 ~= mod(num_year, 100) == 0);
valid_leapyear = true;
switch month1
    case {'September','April','June','November'}
        valid_leapyear = num_day<=30;
    case {'February'}
        valid_leapyear = ~((lpyr && num_day>29) || (~lpyr && num_day>28));
    case {'January', 'March', 'May', 'July', 'August', 'October', 'December'}
        valid_leapyear = num_day<=31;
end
valid = valid_year & valid_month & valid_day & valid_leapyear;
return;
```

Comment: That does work. I don't entirely understand how the return functions works quite yet, but I can search it to find out. I figured ending the statements would save me some heartache and stress.

Comment: @JessicaMarie `return` in a function basically means `end the function, don't process rest of the function code`  and thus save some heartbeats there, CPU heartbeats that is.

Comment: Do you have any opinions as to why it's ignoring my day constraints now? I had it working properly earlier. Your code doesn't appear to have influenced it.

Comment: @JessicaMarie See if the edits for the entire function code make sense to you? Basically we want to flag it for either of the constraints, so if any of those fail, we should flag valid as false and `return back`. It's sort of like when you are in a relationship and you want to make sure the guy fits all the bills and always ready to press the breakup button.

Comment: I was trying to do something like that, but it flags it after February 'Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.' I'm reworking it now.

Comment: I fixed it :) And I used a return function to do it (and my old code) so that's exciting :D I appreciate all the help <3

Comment: @JessicaMarie That's a great way to start a day, aye!? ;)

Comment: I have another beast of a problem to start my day off with, so no lol

Comment: @JessicaMarie Whats with Neuroscience and checking dates for validity and all those string find problems .. doesn't make sense to me! No offense meant tho :)

Answer (score 1):

I made some simple function, using the java interface in matlab. Hope it will be useful.

```
function [valid] = isValidDate(dateStr)
    valid = true;
    dateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat('MMM dd, yyyy');
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try
        dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
        valid = true;
    catch err
        valid = false;
    end       
end
```

Example:

```
isValidDate('December 21, 1934');     % gives 1
isValidDate('December 29.9, -1005.7'); % gives 0
```

Comment: I shouldn't technically use that, since I don't know anything about java or how any of that works :/ But I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Ah I see. But in case for future use, matlab has native [java support](http://goo.gl/kZvkMh). So it can be useful very often. Sometimes there is no sense reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I can also run Python too, but I have to learn it the way the teacher wants me to

Comment: @JessicaMarie Python would also work, but python is not build in matlab. Anyway, good luck with the assignment.